# tkinter width and height understanding

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, height, width

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    master = Tk()
    master.grid()
    label1 = Label(master, width = 60, height = 12, borderwidth = 1, relief = 'solid', bg = #58FAF4')
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan = 2)
    label1.update()
    print(label1.winfo_width(), label1.winfo_height())

    mainloop()

main()
```

Hope I did this posting correct. Just starting with Tkinter, so won't be my first post!  When I execute this code sample, it returns a label size of 424 / 184, so When I have the width and height set to 60 and 20, what is that representing?

Answer (score 1):

> If greater than zero, specifies how much space, in character widths,
> to allocate for the text label. If less than zero, specifies a minimum
> width. If zero or unspecified, the natural width of the text label is
> used.

from the [docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_widget.htm#M-width).

Not every widget in tkinter is specefied in pixels. Widgets, mostlikely to display text, have the width specefied in charackters.